# Prevent access to page based on Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I have an ASP.Net MVC 4 Website. When I started this site I had little to no web programming experience, and I don't believe I set up all of it appropriately.

I have pages, such as Home, Login, Register, which I consider public,
pages like, VerifyPIN and AccountCreated, which I consider internal
and pages like Dashboard and Profile, which are private.

I feel public pages should be accessed by anonymous users, but Login and Register should not be accessible once a user logs in.

Internal pages I want to only be available upon server redirect and never through the browser, aka I don't want a user to be able to type in www.MySite.com/AccountCreated.

And private pages are for a logged in user only.

I feel I have private pages working fine, but I don't know how to limit access to the other pages as described above. Perhaps my notion to not allow a logged in user to access the log in page is miss-found.

My site is relatively small due to the ajax nature of the site. I use [AllowAnonymous] on all public pages but then a logged in user can still access those and I am not sure how to prevent that.

My questions are,

**How can I prevent a user from accessing a page via the address bar (www.MySite.com/AccountCreated)**

**How can I prevent access to a [AllowAnonymous] page once a user has logged in.**

***EDIT***

**Is it normal to prevent logged on users from accessing certain anonymous pages, such as login?**

Comment: what is the scenario for using AccountCreated, is that an action or just a method on the controller?

Comment: Its an Action. It is the page that is displayed after a successful registration, informing the user of the email they are being sent to verify the new account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may always check if user is already logged in. If he did, he will be redirected to another page:

```
public ActionResult AccountCreated(some params)
{
           if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index")
            }
            else
             {
              // login logic here
              }
}
```

You may also check it directly in View:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
   <span> You are already logged in</span>
}
else
{
  //Login form here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well for your first question you can use the [Authorize] action filter.

For your other question, I guess you will have to write your own implementation. You will need to create a new IAuthorizationFilter and use it instead of [AllowAnonymous]

Answer (score 1):

Just some ideas(didn't try them actually).

- For question **1** - if *AccountCreated* is an action that means that the registration form actually POSTs to that URL - **i.e.** It is accessible from outside. I suggest you apply an [HttpPost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute to it so it will process only `POST` requests - there is not much you can do here
- For point two you can do something like this in your action method

> ```
>  if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
>             {
>                 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
>             }
> else return View();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, Signout user when a user goes to `Login` or `Register` page .
Hope you have not provided any link on private pages for a user to go to `login` or `Register` 
page or check if user is authenticated redirect it to `Home` page, frankly you can not stop a user to write a `URL` and pressing the `enter` button, or just give a notification that `You'll be logged out if you proceed to whatever page`.